# How to deny access to Apache port when Nginx proxying

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, nginx

I have installed Apache 2.2.17 and nginx 0.8.53 as load balancer (static for Nginx and PHP for Apache). Everything is working, but when I access mysite.com (default port 80) I get my webpage and can see HTTP headers of nginx server. When I access mysite.com:8080 I get the same page and see headers of Apache2. How can I disable or redirect port 8080 to main domain?

*using CentOS 5. apache and nginx are compiled from their sources.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could bind the service that uses 8080 (apache right?) to localhost instead of your actual IP.
Check for "Listen" in httpd.conf/apache2.conf, and replace with "Bind localhost" and restart the service.

Comment: + changed in `nginx.conf` proxy_pass to 127.0.0.1